# Simplified form of an exp-like sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

I notice that the following series is the taylor expansion at $x=0$ of an $e^x$ function:
$$ e^x = 1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+ ...$$

Recently, I have the following function $f_a(x)$ to simplify, where $a \ (>1)$ is a given constant integer.

$$ f_a(x) = 1+\frac{x^1}{(a+1)!}+\frac{x^2}{(a+2)!}+\frac{x^3}{(a+3)!}+ ...$$

I have a feeling that $f_a(x)$ can be simplifed into a neat form as well. Could anyone give me some hints? If it is hard to simplify it, could you give me a sharp lower bound in the closed-form on $f_a(x)$. Thanks.

Comment: The sum is related to the incomplete gamma function, and it is defined for $a$ not necessarily an integer (as is assumed in an answer below.)  Knowing this, you can rely on the work of others, such as determining an asymptotic expansion that is uniform in both $a$ and $x.$  The work of N. Temme comes to mind.  You can also turn it into an integral, which may be computationally easier.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
(f_a(x)-1)\,x^a + \sum_{k=0}^a \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x
$$
When we solve for $f_a(x)$, we get
$$
f_a(x) = x^{-a} \left(e^x - \sum_{k=0}^a \frac{x^k}{k!} \right) +1 
\;\;\;\text{for}\;\; x\neq 0
$$
and $f_a(0) = 1.$

Comment: We need to specify $f_a(0)=1$.

Comment: @saulspatz You are right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As @skbmoore commented, this is related to the incomplete gamma function
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n}{(a+n)!}=\frac{e^x}{x^a}\left( 1-\frac{\Gamma (a+1,x)}{\Gamma (a+1)}\right)$$ Therefore
$$f_a(x)=1+\frac{e^x}{x^a}\left( 1-\frac{\Gamma (a+1,x)}{\Gamma (a+1)}\right)$$ which works even for non-integer values of $a$.

Similarly
$$\sum_{n=1}^p \frac {x^n}{(a+n)!}=\frac{e^x}{x^a}\left(\frac{\Gamma (a+p+1,x)}{\Gamma (a+p+1)}-\frac{\Gamma (a+1,x)}{\Gamma (a+1)}\right)$$

There are many papers dealing with the asymptotics of the incomplete gamma function (have a look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11)).